# Variant of Dekker's algorithm confusion

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

This program execute two different threads and tell me who the winner of the "race" is.

Unexpectedly sometimes BOTH threads "wins" (I expected someone or no one to win). Is this expected behaviour and why? I'm obviously missing something fundamental here.

```
class Program
{
    public volatile static int a = 0; 
    public volatile static int b = 0;

    public static void Main()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            a = 0; 
            b = 0;

            Parallel.Invoke(delegate { a = 1; if (b == 0) Console.WriteLine("A wins"); },
                            delegate { b = 1; if (a == 0) Console.WriteLine("B wins"); });

            Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.NewLine);

            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
A wins

B wins

A wins
B wins

A wins

...
```

Comment: When changing the implementation from `Parallel` to poor old `Thread`s, it seems to works.(don't know why yet.)

Comment: @L.B: Interesting, it's probably because the threads run on the same processor-core?

Comment: setting `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` also seems to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using volatile incorrectly:

declaring the variables volatile is not enough, you need to make sure that **everywhere** you read/write them, you use `Thread.VolatileRead(ref myVar)`/`Thread.VolatileWrite(ref myVar)`

Also, volatile does **NOT** ensure read/write order (from different threads), even if used correctly. Browse SO for information on the topic. **EDIT: [it seems to do](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2004/08/05/Dont-get-C-volatile-the-wrong-way.aspx) on a x86 single core machine**

You could simply use the `lock` statement, but if you want to get to the bottom of this, I recommand reading, understanding, then reading again [this free e-book](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

**ADDITIONS:**
I just browsed through the `Parallel` class in .NET 4, and nowhere the `volatile` keyword is used.
They also copy the array of `Action<T>` before looping over it for some reason, but I doubt that impacts you.

Comment: +1. Using Thread.VolatileRead(ref myVar) etc. does actually give the expected behaviour. My guesses are (and what I wanted to see in the first place) that the results of not declaring the variables as volatile (not inserting the correct memory barriers) give an good example of the somehow relaxed memory model. If you want to elaborate on that feel free. I will probably mark this as accepted if not a more detailed explanation of WHY this happens is given. Thanks!

Comment: @JK. read the free e-book for *detailed* explanation (but brace yourself!).

Comment: I read the ebook. From my understanding the VolatileRead adds a MemoryBarrier. However, this does not guarantee that the second thread will be able to read the "fresh" value that the first thread wrote. So, even though this works, I think that theoretically it shouldn't (at least using the VolatileRead and VolatieWrite methods).

Answer (score 1):

Both Win when they execute in parallel.

From the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke.aspx): Executes each of the provided actions, **possibly in parallel**.

Comment: That's still odd. a and b are volatile and they are updated before checking the value in the other task. That means that at the moment when a is checking if b == 1, a at least must be 1 and vice versa, so it seems that logically at most one can win.

Comment: @GolezTrol that would make sense, but even though they are declared as volatile, they are not used as such: he gets/sets without using Volatile.Read/Volatile.Write

Comment: @GolezTrol Hi! I think that volatile works as it is supposed to work on multi-threaded single core processors; when you have multi-thread n-core processors the case is a bit different and more tricky: http://www.jaylee.org/post/2004/08/05/Dont-get-C-volatile-the-wrong-way.aspx

Comment: @trenpixter: The link you posted might give a hint (I'm not sure). That some reads are bypassing the assignment because of buffered writes in the processor. There is as far as I know nothing that volatile can do to stop this behaviour. Does the .NET memory consistency model allow this?

Comment: @JK: Baboon just answered that:) And gave us some awesome reading material!

Comment: +1: it's indeed a good catch. The book i linked might consume all your time today though ;)